# Flex 2.4 login page with tokens

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-viewer, arcgis-10.0

I am using AGS security and a 2.4 flex application.
I would like to login with a login screen like available in the samples.
Then utilize tokens for fc security on my services.

I see a sample for both of these on esri.resources.com but nothing for both together.
Has anyone done this that can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login secure services widget provides a solution for dynamic map services.
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5c6e065e885948fd8ab0e570073c8224

Comment: I have contracted for services. I really don't like the solution they came up with. I wish ESRI would develop or publish, a comprehensive (SSL, global_id, token based, solution). allowing sde user/permission generation with group assignment at the service level.